# How to generate SOAP message without WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap, ibm-mq

I need to integrate my C#/.NET application on an other system in our organization, which is exposing IBM WebSphere MQ endpoint. Im able to connect to MQ Queue and put a message into it, but I have a trouble with creating a payload of the message. The payload is required to be a good old SOAP message in form of a string. So I need to generate the SOAP message, but I dont have a WCF infrastructure involved in this case. All I have are XSDs for SOAP header and payload, and I think this should be enough to generate a message, but I dont know, how to construct a SOAP message without WCF.

I considered this:

1. Construct the SOAP message purely by myself using XmlDocument class. I dont like this idea.
2. Generate contract classes from XSDs and build the message in the way as in the case of WCF, but somehow serialize the message to a string and send it over MQ message.

Can you please point me to a solution using 2) approach? Or are there any other ways?

Thank you,
Michal

Comment: Have a look at https://wscfblue.codeplex.com/